# How to switch connected user in outlook Harmon.ie

Tags: harmon.ie

I created a new outlook profile with a different 365 account mailbox before deleting the old one. When opening outlook with the new profile Harmon.ie was still connected to the old 365 mailbox's account. I deleted Harmon.ie and reinstalled but it still had the old account connected. How do I switch it to the new 365 account?

Thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

Harmon.ie intentionally keeps sites settings.
You need to remove the registered site from harmon.ie options  or delete file "C:\Users[user_name]\AppData\Roaming\Mainsoft\Harmony.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings\com.mainsoft.sharepoint.sidebar.prefs" then restart Outlook.

---- Jean